# The conflict occurred in database ecommerce-app-db, table dbo.Movies, column 'Id'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This problem is occurring  when I am trying to insert data into the database:

[image]

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Actors_Movies_Movies_MovieId". The conflict occurred in database "ecommerce-app-db", table "dbo.Movies", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

This is my migration C# code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace eTickets.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Actors",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    ProfilePictureURL = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    FullName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Bio = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Actors", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Cinemas",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Logo = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Cinemas", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Producers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    ProfilePictureURL = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    FullName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Bio = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Producers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Movies",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    Price = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                    ImageURL = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    StartDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    EndDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                    MovieCategory = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    CinemaId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ProducerId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Movies", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Movies_Cinemas_CinemaId",
                        column: x => x.CinemaId,
                        principalTable: "Cinemas",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Movies_Producers_ProducerId",
                        column: x => x.ProducerId,
                        principalTable: "Producers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Actors_Movies",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    MovieId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ActorId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Actors_Movies", x => new { x.ActorId, x.MovieId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Actors_Movies_Actors_ActorId",
                        column: x => x.ActorId,
                        principalTable: "Actors",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Actors_Movies_Movies_MovieId",
                        column: x => x.MovieId,
                        principalTable: "Movies",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Actors_Movies_MovieId",
                table: "Actors_Movies",
                column: "MovieId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Movies_CinemaId",
                table: "Movies",
                column: "CinemaId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Movies_ProducerId",
                table: "Movies",
                column: "ProducerId");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Actors_Movies");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Actors");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Movies");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Cinemas");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Producers");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to insert this data :

```
if (!context.Actors_Movies.Any())
{
    context.Actors_Movies.AddRange(new List<Actor_MovieModel>()
    {
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 1,
                MovieId = 1
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 3,
                MovieId = 1
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 1,
                MovieId = 2
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 4,
                MovieId = 2
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 1,
                MovieId = 3
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 2,
                MovieId = 3
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 5,
                MovieId = 3
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 2,
                MovieId = 4
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 3,
                MovieId = 4
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 4,
                MovieId = 4
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 2,
                MovieId = 5
            },
        new Actor_MovieModel()
            {
                ActorId = 3,
                MovieId = 5
            },
            // .... and so on .....
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is my table relationship code:

```
    public int CinemaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CinemaId")]
    public CinemaModel Cinema { get; set; }

    //Producer
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProducerId")]
    public ProducerModel Producer { get; set; }
```

I do not understand what this exception wants to convey.

Comment: Have you added any movies to your database before adding the actors? The error message is telling you that you are adding an actor movie record, where the movie id does not exist in the movies table.

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text.

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration Jonathan and Dale K, I will apply these changes which you are telling